# Sorting out a discrepancy between a pdf generated by FOP v0.20.5 and v2.1

Tags: pdf, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am currently trying to upgrade our application's FOP dependency from version 0.20.5 to 2.1, and I'm comparing the PDFs generated by various XSL-FO documents in order to minimize the chance that the PDF output looks different to our users.

Here is one of the XSL-FO documents that I'm using to test:

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in" master-name="standard">
         <fo:region-body margin-left="0.25in"
                         margin-right="0.25in"
                         margin-top="0.5in"
                         margin-bottom="1.00in"/>
         <fo:region-before extent="0.25in"/>
         <fo:region-after extent="0.5in"/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
   </fo:layout-master-set>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="standard" force-page-count="no-force">
      <fo:static-content margin-left="0.25in"
                         margin-right="0.25in"
                         flow-name="xsl-region-before">
         <fo:block text-align="center"/>
      </fo:static-content>
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <fo:block>
            <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" wrap-option="wrap"/>
            <fo:block padding="5px">
               <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
                  <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)"/>
                  <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)"/>
                  <fo:table-header>
                     <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell border="0.25pt solid #999"
                                       font-size="10pt"
                                       font-weight="bold"
                                       padding="5pt"
                                       text-align="left">
                           <fo:block>TEST</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell border="0.25pt solid #999"
                                       font-size="10pt"
                                       font-weight="bold"
                                       padding="5pt"
                                       text-align="right">
                           <fo:block>TEST</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                     </fo:table-row>
                  </fo:table-header>
                  <fo:table-body>
                     <fo:table-row>
                     <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block/>
                     </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                  </fo:table-body>
               </fo:table>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block padding="5px"/>
            <fo:block padding="5px"/>
            <fo:block padding="5px">
               <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
                  <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)"/>
                  <fo:table-header>
                     <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell border="0.25pt solid #999"
                                       font-size="10pt"
                                       font-weight="bold"
                                       padding="5pt"
                                       text-align="center">
                           <fo:block>
                              <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
                                 <fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="50%"/>
                                 <fo:table-column column-number="2" column-width="50%"/>
                                 <fo:table-body vertical-align="middle">
                                    <fo:table-row>
                                       <fo:table-cell>
                                          <fo:block text-align="left">TEST</fo:block>
                                       </fo:table-cell>
                                       <fo:table-cell>
                                          <fo:block text-align="end">TEST</fo:block>
                                       </fo:table-cell>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                 </fo:table-body>
                              </fo:table>
                           </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                     </fo:table-row>
                  </fo:table-header>
                  <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                     <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block/>
                     </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                  </fo:table-body>
               </fo:table>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block padding="5px"/>
            <fo:block font-size="16pt" padding="2px">TEST</fo:block>
            <fo:block padding="5px">
               <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
                  <fo:table-column column-width="1in"/>
                  <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)"/>
                  <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)"/>
                  <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)"/>
                  <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)"/>
                  <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)"/>
                  <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)"/>
                  <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)"/>
                  <fo:table-header>
                     <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell border="0.25pt solid #999"
                                       font-size="10pt"
                                       font-weight="bold"
                                       padding="5pt"
                                       text-align="left">
                           <fo:block>TEST</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell border="0.25pt solid #999"
                                       font-size="10pt"
                                       font-weight="bold"
                                       padding="5pt"
                                       text-align="center">
                           <fo:block>TEST</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell border="0.25pt solid #999"
                                       font-size="10pt"
                                       font-weight="bold"
                                       padding="5pt"
                                       text-align="center">
                           <fo:block>TEST</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell border="0.25pt solid #999"
                                       font-size="10pt"
                                       font-weight="bold"
                                       padding="5pt"
                                       text-align="center">
                           <fo:block>TEST</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell border="0.25pt solid #999"
                                       font-size="10pt"
                                       font-weight="bold"
                                       padding="5pt"
                                       text-align="center">
                           <fo:block>TEST</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell border="0.25pt solid #999"
                                       font-size="10pt"
                                       font-weight="bold"
                                       padding="5pt"
                                       text-align="center">
                           <fo:block>TEST</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell border="0.25pt solid #999"
                                       font-size="10pt"
                                       font-weight="bold"
                                       padding="5pt"
                                       text-align="center">
                           <fo:block>TEST</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell border="0.25pt solid #999"
                                       font-size="10pt"
                                       font-weight="bold"
                                       padding="5pt"
                                       text-align="center">
                           <fo:block>TEST</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                     </fo:table-row>
                  </fo:table-header>
                  <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                     <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block/>
                     </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                  </fo:table-body>
               </fo:table>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block hyphenate="true"
                      language="en"
                      wrap-option="wrap"
                      font-weight="bold">Test sentence</fo:block>
         </fo:block>
         <fo:block id="last-page"/>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

With v2.1 the border of the table-headers is thinner and the spacing of the various pdf elements is slightly greater than that in the v0.20.5 generated PDF. These differences may seem minor, but with larger documents the spacing issue becomes more and more apparent.

I've tried moving the border attributes to different elements (e.g. fo:table-row, fo:block) to no avail.

Here are pictures of the generated reports. Opening them in two tabs and flipping between them will make their differences more apparent.

PDF generated with v0.20.5:
[image: Report with v0.20.5]

PDF generated with v2.1
[image: Report with v2.1]

Any help determining why there are these minor discrepancies between the 2 generated reports would be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: Without knowing anything about FOP, it looks like borders collapsing or not

Comment: So try changing all your borders in the new test to not collapse and see